# Restfull API issue with encoding/decoding hexas

Tags: python, flask

I have created a Restfull API in a local server with Flask.
I am getting some troubles with encoding/decoding of hexas.

I have created a function to debug my issue which is :

```
class test_encoding(Resource) :
    def get(self,val):
        return{'data': val}

api.add_resource(test_encoding,'/testencoding/<val>')
```

For exemple if I use as a request in Chrome :

```
.../testencoding/%23
```

I get this response (hexas encoding) :

```
{"data": "#"}
```

But I want to keep my string as it has been written in Chrome, with the `%` :

```
{"data": "%23"}
```

I know I have to play with encoding and decoding but I am quite lost.
Can you help me ?

Thanks in advance for your help,
LCMa

**UPDATE**

As I tried to get the url thanks to request.url and it returned the same '#' instead of '%23', I understood that the URL is automaticly modified.
My idea is then to get back the request url that is shown in the prompt :

```
(base) C:\Users\maell\PycharmProjects\Serveur>python app.py
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Mar/2019 10:02:53] "GET /testencoding/%23 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

We see that here, the url is print in the way I want it.
**But how to get this from the console ? Is it possible ?**

Comment: Had the same problem, what I did was to put whatever data you need in the request body instead of the url. Would love to learn myself if there's a way to have it in the URL.

Comment: Have you tried URL encoding your URL: ".../testencoding/%2523".

Comment: I have tried by adding val.replace('%','%25') in my get function but it does not work because I think val is already turn into '#' (if the input is %23). So I don't really see where to do this URL encoding ...

Comment: @RnD : Was it for a GET request ? Because a GET request usually can't have a request body

Comment: @LCMa you can put it in a ```GET``` but that's bad practice, from your example it should be either a ```POST``` or a ```PUT```, I'll post an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can do it both ways, I'm receiving project id from the URL because it's just a number but the name had special characters which were stripped from the URL, so the only way is to put it in the request body.

```py
@projects.route("/<project_id>/configurations/<configuration_id>/rename", methods=['PUT'])
    new_name = json.loads(request.data)['name']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works well for what I want to do !